# Accidental quantization in BGR to HSV conversion

Tags: c++, opencv, opencv3.0, hsv

I am trying to convert a BGR image to HSV. When I write out the H channel of the conversion, it has a strange blocky structure that I'm guessing means something got accidentally quantized along the way. I tried converting my BGR unsigned char image to float first, but the result is the same. Here is my code:

```
// STL
#include <iostream>

// OpenCV
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>

void Float(const std::string& inputFilename)
{
    cv::Mat image = cv::imread(inputFilename, CV_LOAD_IMAGE_COLOR); // Loads as BGR

    cv::Mat floatImage;
    image.convertTo(floatImage, CV_32FC3);

    cv::Mat hsvImage;
    cv::cvtColor(floatImage, hsvImage, CV_BGR2HSV);

    std::vector<cv::Mat> hsvChannels;
    cv::split(hsvImage, hsvChannels);

    cv::imwrite("h_float.png", hsvChannels[0]);

}

void Original(const std::string& inputFilename)
{
    cv::Mat image = cv::imread(inputFilename, CV_LOAD_IMAGE_COLOR); // Loads as BGR

    cv::Mat hsvImage;
    cv::cvtColor(image, hsvImage, CV_BGR2HSV);

    std::vector<cv::Mat> hsvChannels;
    cv::split(hsvImage, hsvChannels);

    cv::imwrite("h_original.png", hsvChannels[0]);

}

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    std::string inputFilename = argv[1];

    Original(inputFilename);
    Float(inputFilename);

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

and here is the input:
[image]

and the output (h_original.png):
[image]

and the output (h_float.png):
[image]

Any suggestion as to what I'm doing wrong here?

Comment: what is the wrong with the output? seems logical for me

Comment: @HumamHelfawi It is very "blocky". The H image (or the S, or the V) should look  like a grayscale-ish version of the original image, right? That is, it should be as smoothly varying as the original image. Why are all of these rectangular artifacts/edges being introduced?

Comment: I am not sure but your image seems to have very low range color space (white and its degrees)

Comment: @HumamHelfawi That shouldn't change the smoothness. RGB is a continuous space and HSV is also a continuous space, so the mapping should not be quantized like this.

Comment: Yes  it is continuous but just on N. However, this is not the point of course. Consider this case :  image of black shape with light and shadow on it. all the shape is black so it will be mapped to same H and S value (almost). but V will contain very smooth and different values.

Comment: See my edit on my answer please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are doing everything in the right way. I tried your image on my machine and got the same results. I think this result is due to the low color range of your image. This the result of the 3 channels of HSV. H and S suffer from this problem. However, V is smooth because it is about the light condition not the color.

[image: H-channel]

[image: S-channel]

[image: V-channel]

**EDIT:**

To make my point clearer, see this image and the output using the same code:

[image: Original RGB]

[image: H-channel]

[image: S-channel]

[image: V-channel]

**Another EDIT (Black problem):**

In `HSV`: `if V=0 then it is black` whatever the rest `S` and `H` are.
So to check if the color is black you have just to check the V component and there is no meaning if checking the other.

**Math proof:**

```
C = V × S
X = C × (1 - |(H / 60º) mod 2 - 1|)
m = V - C
```

[image: HSV-RGB]

It is clear that when `V=0` and whatever `H,S` are, we will have:
`C=0 , X=0` which leads to `R,G,B=(0,0,0)`

Comment: So can you explain why the headboard which is to any reasonable approximation "the same color" or at the least "very smoothly varying" ends up with very very sharp, rectangular edges in the H image? And the same for the blanket on the bed, particularly the lower right corner? It also seems curious that these rectangles are image-aligned (i.e. exactly vertical)?

Comment: Not that hard. Go here http://www.rapidtables.com/convert/color/rgb-to-hsv.htm  and see what is the HSV for this RGB value (0,0,0), (1,2,3) they are both black and no human eye can see the diffrence. But the H value will be a surprise :)

Comment: So is there a better color space to represent the "color" of an image (the same type of thing that H in HSV does) but that doesn't have these strange effects? I'm trying to detect "color edges", so these artifacts are really problematic as the edge detection algorithms really latch onto them.

Comment: what do you extacyl mean by color edges ? you may ask another question with samples input/output